# Convert an image array to a binarized image with a specific threshehold

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, binary

So, i am extracting pixel values of the three channels **R**, **G**, and **B** of an **JPG** image, and then I'm calculating some index using the three channels. Which gives me a **numpy array** : `Indice`

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy

Image = plt.imread("/home/stagiaire/Bureau/image_mais_rgb.JPG")

blue = Image[:,:,0]
green = Image[:,:,1]
red= Image[:,:,2]

with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    r = red / red + green + blue 
    g = green / red + green + blue 
    b = blue / red + green + blue 

ExGRE = 2*g-r-b
ExRED = 1.4*r-b
Indice = ExGRE - ExRED
Indice_Image = Indice.astype(numpy.uint8)
```

Now I want to convert this image array to binarized image and to choose a threshehold near 0 (0.1 or 0.2). How can I do it in **Python36** ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be as simple as `Indice_Image > 0.1 or 0.2`?

Comment: I didn't though of something like this but, how do you do this ? i just tried soemthing like : `for Indice_Image.all > 0.1 :
    plt.subplots() ; plt.imshow(Indice_Image) ; plt.title("Indice")`

Comment: But it doesn't work

Comment: I also tried this list comprehension: `A = [i for i in Indice_Image.any() if i > 0.1]`